# how to remove all the string after a word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, html, split

I want to remove all the string after a word in javascript like in my case remove everything after "share something "

```
bla 
bla bla 

share something ...

bla bla bla 
<image tag></img>
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla 
<image tag></img>
```

Comment: Start from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#String_Object)

Comment: You better wrap "bla.." value inside a tag like span, div etc.

Comment: ITS already inside a div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done the following way :

```
var input='bla\n\nbla\n\nShare something ...\n\nbla bla bla\n<image tag></img>bla\n<image tag></img>';

var output = input.split('Share something')[0]+'Share something';

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to tokenize and you can use [**split**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) for that:

Split a string into an array of substrings:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

And to get the first token: **res[0]** is equal to **"How"**

In the above example, the delimiter is a space character. For your specific case, you could make the delimiter **"share something "**:

```
var str = "bla\n\nbla\n\nshare something ...\n\nbla bla bla\n<image tag></img>bla\n<image tag></img>"
var res = str.split("share something ");
```

Using [**slice**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) you can get a piece of the array:

```
var whatyouwant = res.slice(0,0) + "share something";
```

Or

```
var whatyouwant = res[0] + "share something";
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove everything after "share something", and keep the rest part. In this case, the desired result is `bla 
bla bla 

share something`

Comment: Won't  'remove everything after share something' mean to delete everything after `"share something "` ?

Comment: The idea is to get a piece of an string with a delimiter.

Comment: I know what the idea is. Thats what I did i.e. deleting everything from the string after the given word. You have edited your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `String.prototype.indexOf` and `String.prototype.substring`:

```
var seekString = "Share something...";

var str = "Lots of text<br>Share something...<br>More text and stuff";
var idx = str.indexOf(seekString);

console.log("The index is:"+idx);
if (idx !== -1) {
  var result = str.substring(0, idx + seekString.length);
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: solution is too complex :(